# removing query strings from canonical URL

Tags: php, html, canonical-link

I use PHP to echo the current URL in `<link rel="canonical" href="URL" />` on my static website, but unfortunately it also echoes query strings along with it.

`http://www.example.com?querystring` gets echoed in canonical, and I'm trying to find a away to echo URLs ignoring query strings and whatever follows it.

I am currently using .

Is there a way I can declare all the necessary code for this once in a global template, and simply `echo $url` wherever I require the URL without query strings?

Comment: Grab the part of the URL up to the '?' character? It should be rather simple.

Comment: How can I specify that in PHP? The code I'm using just fetches the current exact URL from the server.

Comment: Well the URL is a string so there are many ways to do it, like the one given by DeiForm. Just look at string functions

Comment: How are you grabbing the current URL? `$_SERVER` variables?

Comment: I'm using `<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url; ?>`. Is there a simple way I can state the code once to clear query strings and get the URI, and simply echo $var anywhere I need the whole thing?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you ahve your URL in variable. Then we will explode the url with delimiter "?" and then echo only the first index of returned array:

```
$url = http://www.example.com?querystring;
$array = explode("?", $url);
$yourUrl = $array[0];
```

There you go

Comment: or `list($yourUrl) =  explode("?", $url);`

Answer (score 1):

for example you can use parse_url and re-build your query

```
$url = "http://www.example.com?querystring";

$newUrl = parse_url($url);

echo "http://".$newUrl['host'].$newUrl['path'];
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

use request.forwardURI to set canonical uri, it removes the query string paramaters